# How can I handle keystrokes without hanging in MASM32

Tags: assembly, user-input, keystroke, masm32

I am trying to write a console application using MASM32. I have googled how to get keystroke values, but it seems like I keep getting suggestions that are either using interrupts (INT), or something using INVOKE but hangs while waiting for the keystroke.

Is there a way to get a keystroke, which returns immediately if no key was pressed? Or something which checks if a key was pressed, like kbhit?

I am very new to MASM32, and assembly programming in general, so sorry if this seems like a trivial question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd have to call the Win32 Console API. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686971(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I read the page and it seems like you are suggesting invoking a C function in assembly? Also, it uses a buffer to get characters from STDIN, am I able to do this in assembly?

Comment: The Console API is part of the Windows API, so although the code in the examples is in _C++_, the API calls in the _C++_  code can be invoked from assembler.

Comment: MASM32 has header files that may help. I think it might be masm32rt.inc .

Comment: You're probably using at least one of those "C functions" already (`ExitProcess`).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to see if there's a specific function in there I need.